# Merge 3 times 2 columns at a time into one in only one Command

Tags: mysql, merge

I have a little problem that I haven't been able to find a solution for yet.

Language: MySQL.

I have a table that contains the Names and Family names of 3 different people in one row, of course they're in 6 columns

Example :

```
Name1  |  Surname1  |  Name2  |  Surname2  |  Name3  |  Surname3  |
a      |  a         |  b      |  b         |  c      |  c         |
d      |  d         |  e      |  e         |  f      |  f         |
```

And so on...

Now I want these names in a select, to be shown as full names, for example :

```
Name1         |  Name2          |  Name3         |
a,a           |  b,b            |  c,c           |
```

How can I achieve that? I've tried:

```
SELECT (name1, surname1) as name1, (name2, surname2) as name2, (name3, surname3) as name3 from Table;
```

And the same with `+ ' ' +` instead of commas as well, and I'm not sure as to how I could solve my problem.

Comment: You should use the `CONCAT` function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(name1, ', ', surname1) as name1, CONCAT(name2, ', ', surname2) as name2, CONCAT(name3, ', ', surname3) as name3 from Table;
```